# Open-source improvements or replacements for Swing components

Tags: java, swing, components

I develop a number of desktop Java applications using Swing, and while Swing is quite powerful (once you get the hang of it), there are still a lot of cases where I wish some advanced component was available right out of the box.

For example, I'd really like to see easy-to-use components (without writing them myself, which I could do given enough time) like:

- Multi-line label
- Windows File Explorer-like Icons or Thumbnails view
- Drop-down button (like Firefox's old Back button)
- 5-star rating widget
- Combo box with automatic history (like the text field on Google)
- An Outlook-style accordion-style bar
- and so on

I know of a couple of sources of free Swing components, like [SwingLabs](http://swinglabs.org), home of JXTable, JXDatePicker, and a few others.

**Where do you go for Swing components beyond those included with Java itself?**

Comment: Multi-line labels are built into Swing because you can use HTML in JLabels: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685521/multiline-text-in-jlabel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following are worth a look:

- [swingX](https://swingx.dev.java.net/)
- [Glazed lists](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/)
- [Substance look'n'feel](https://substance.dev.java.net/)
- [Flamingo components](https://flamingo.dev.java.net/)
- [Ken Orr's Mac Widgets](http://code.google.com/p/macwidgets/)
- [Jide's open source components](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm)

Answer (score 1):

As for: "Windows File Explorer-like Icons or Thumbnails view"

They are built in in swing.

File explorer icons are accessed through FileSystemView class ( it is used by JFileChooser ) when the L&F is Windows of course.

```
FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
Icon driveIcon = fsv.getSystemIcon( new File("C:\\"));
```

And the Thumbnails  icon can be retrieved with the sun.com class that are discouraged  by Sun

```
sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder getIcon( boolean largeIcon )
```

But this one  may not perform very well some times ( due to native resources handling I think ).

Comment: I realize that... I was thinking about lists that look like Explorer views, but aren't used for the file system.  For example, a thumbnail list of photos, or some other type of icon.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can get an awesome wrapping labe and an accordion from [javaswingcomponents](http://www.javaswingcomponents.com/products), however they are not open source implementations.

Otherwise Jide and SwingX are great choices.