# Multiline JLabels - Java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I want `JLabel` text in multiline format otherwise text will be too long.  How can we do this in Java?

Answer (score 11):

If you don't mind wrapping your label text in an `html` tag, the JLabel will automatically word wrap it when its container's width is too narrow to hold it all. For example try adding this to a GUI and then resize the GUI to be too narrow - it will wrap:

```
new JLabel("<html>This is a really long line that I want to wrap around.</html>");
```

Comment: And you can use <br /> in there as well!

Answer (score 8):

I recommend creating your own custom component that emulates the JLabel style while wrapping:

```
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class TextNote extends JTextArea {
    public TextNote(String text) {
        super(text);
        setBackground(null);
        setEditable(false);
        setBorder(null);
        setLineWrap(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);
        setFocusable(false);
    }
}
```

Then you just have to call:

```
new TextNote("Here is multiline content.");
```

Make sure that you set the amount of rows (`textNote.setRows(2)`) if you want to `pack()` to calculate the height of the parent component correctly.

Comment: A couple of additions to recreate the look and feel of a real label:

    `setOpaque(false);`
    `setFont(UIManager.getFont("Label.font"));`

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use a JTextArea instead of a JLabel

and on your JTextArea you can use the method .setWrapStyleWord(true) to change line at the end of a word.

Comment: JTextArea is for editing text, JLabel for displaying...

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to [use (basic) CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766175/word-wrap-in-jbuttons/5767825#5767825) in the HTML.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

MultiLine Label with auto adjust height.
Wrap text in Label

```
private void wrapLabelText(JLabel label, String text) {
    FontMetrics fm = label.getFontMetrics(label.getFont());
    PlainDocument doc = new PlainDocument();
    Segment segment = new Segment();
    try {
        doc.insertString(0, text, null);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {

    }

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("<html>");
    int noOfLine = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length();) {
        try {
            doc.getText(i, text.length() - i, segment);
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            throw new Error("Can't get line text");
        }
        int breakpoint = Utilities.getBreakLocation(segment, fm, 0, this.width - pointerSignWidth - insets.left - insets.right, null, 0);
        sb.append(text.substring(i, i + breakpoint));
        sb.append("<br/>");
        i += breakpoint;

        noOfLine++;
    }
    sb.append("</html>");
    label.setText(sb.toString());

    labelHeight = noOfLine * fm.getHeight();
    setSize();
}
```

Thanks,
Jignesh Gothadiya