# How to add a multi line text to a JButton with the line unknown? (dynamically)

Tags: java, html, swing, jbutton, multiline

How do you make the text on a `JButton` multiline?  I have read that most use HTML, but what happens when it is dynamic and you don't know the size of the lines, or what the lines are?

Right now the text on my button just ends with `...`  as opposed to making a new line.

Most other methods assume you know the string and are hard coded, so you can't do this on the fly.

Edited: I created a method that will do this dynamically for a button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word Wrap in JButtons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766175/word-wrap-in-jbuttons) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861724/is-there-some-word-wrap-property-of-jlabel-exist/7861833#7861833).

Comment: Answer didn't solve my question, so I added an answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770776/how-to-split-a-jbutton-java-text-into-multiple-lines-without-knowing-the-line?noredirect=1#comment22417716_15770776

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll need to at least know how each line is delimited. For example if lines are delimited with newline characters, you could do:

```
String twoLines = "Two\nLines";
JButton b = 
    new JButton("<html>" + twoLines.replaceAll("\\n", "<br>") + "</html>");
```

Comment: That only works when the long text already contains information re. line breaks.  Using CSS to style the raw text (see links above) is more robust and versatile.