# How to split a JButton (JAVA) text into multiple lines without knowing the line UNTIL CREATION

Tags: java, jbutton

How do you split a long line into multiple lines so it will fit in a button?

Most other answers have used HTML but they hard code the string into the line making it impossible to split the line on the fly as the button is being created.

Edited: I added a method to do this after researching, asking and not getting a good answer on how to do this dynamically.

Please share your methods

Comment: This question is not clear. Are you asking how to line-wrap a long string?

Because if you are this is not a java or jbutton question.

Comment: When someone makes a JButton and wants to have multiple lines on the text (text on the button), everyone suggests a JTextFrame, or some other hack... I wanted to know how to do it without using one of these superflous hacks, and just dealing with a string and the button.setText method

Comment: @waf You answered your own question.

Comment: Yes I did, after asking a few times before, and no one gave an answer on how to do it dynamically (all were hard coded). But I would love to see other answers that do it better. I added my method to make it easier for people who want to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sample method that splits a line dynamically using HTML tags

```
/**
         * This method divides the button text into lines by applying
         * html tags. Only way to get multiple lines on a JButton.
         * @param string
         * @return
         */
        private String wrapText(String string){
            //Return string initialized with opening html tag
            String returnString="<html>";

            //Get max width of text line
            int maxLineWidth = new ImageIcon("Images/buttonBackground.png").getIconWidth()-10;

            //Create font metrics
            FontMetrics metrics = this.getFontMetrics(new Font("Helvetica Neue", Font.PLAIN, 15));

            //Current line width
            int lineWidth=0;

            //Iterate over string
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(string," ");
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                String word = (String) tokenizer.nextElement(); 
                int stringWidth = metrics.stringWidth(word);

                //If word will cause a spill over max line width
                if (stringWidth+lineWidth>=maxLineWidth) {

                    //Add a new line, add a break tag and add the new word
                    returnString=(returnString+"<br>"+word);

                    //Reset line width
                    lineWidth=0;
                }else{

                    //No spill, so just add to current string
                    returnString=(returnString+" "+word);
                }
                //Increase the width of the line
                lineWidth+=stringWidth;
            }

            //Close html tag
            returnString=(returnString+"<html>");

            //Return the string
            return returnString;
        }
```