# Using stringWidth with html String

Tags: java, html, fontmetrics

This is probably a very easy question, but as I don't really know what I'm looking for, I couldn't succeed to find the solution...

I'm using a JLabel inside which I put a html string. My string is obtained by Jsoup Then, I want to resize the JLabel to make it fit the string. For that, I'm using the FontMetrics.stringWidth method which works fine... Except in the case I have special characters, such as "è", "ç", "ô", etc. In this case, the characters becomes sth like `&ocirc;`, or `&eacute;`, and the stringWidth takes it into account.

for instance, FontMetrics.stringWidth(HTMLFormating("é")) will give me the stringWidth of ("`&eacute;`") which is far longer... My expected result is that when I measure the length of "`&eacute;`chec" for instance, I get the same result as for "echec"

What is the solution ? Is there a way to transform back the html string into a "normal" string ? Or should I use another method ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Just [check the preferred size of the label](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5767825/418556) once the `String` has been added.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, you're right ! It perfectly works. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the [preferred size of the label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5767825/418556) once the String has been added.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should probably post the code that you're using to resize the JLabel. I'll address that issue though because it's probably the one that causing your problem.

```
public void resize(String newText){
    label.setText(newText);
    label.setFont (font);
    int labelW = (int) Math.ceil (label.getPreferredSize().getWidth());
    int maxWidth = (int) Math.floor (panel.getSize().getWidth());
    if (labelW <= maxWidth)
        return;
    for (int k = 1 ; labelW > maxWidth ; k++) {
        Font labelFont = font.deriveFont (font.getSize() - k*1.0f);
        label.setFont (labelFont);
        labelW = (int) Math.ceil (label.getPreferredSize().getWidth());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my browser bugged and I didn't saw that a part of my question was missing after recovering it. My problem is not about resizing, it's about the fact that I have to measure the width of an "html-formated" string such as "échec" (5 characters) which becomes `&eacute;`chec (12 characters), and I would like to get the width of "echec" instead. Thank you !