# Setting Font and Colors to different parts of String that is contained in one JLabel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

How should I do that for this `String`?

`Orb of Deception Range: 880 Cooldown: 7 Cost: 70/75/80/85/90 Mana`

I want to have color blue and size 14 for `"Orb of Deception"`, and `"Range"`/`"Cooldown"`/`"Cost"` color black size 12, and the numbers color green and size 10.

It must be contained in one `JLabel`.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Word Wrap in JButtons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766175/word-wrap-in-jbuttons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.G.  (adjust to need)

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ColoredLabel {

    static String text =
            "<html>"
            + "<head>"
            + "<style type='text/css'>"
            + ".name {"
            + " font-size: 16px;"
            + " color: blue;"
            + "}"
            + ".value {"
            + " font-size: 12px;"
            + " color: green;"
            + "}"
            + "</style>"
            + "</head>"
            + "<body>"
            + "<h1>Orb of Deception</h1>"
            + "<table border=1>"
            + "<tr><td class='name'>Range</td><td class='value'>880</td></tr>"
            + "<tr><td class='name'>Cost</td><td class='value'>70/75/80/85/90 Mana</td></tr>"
            + "<tr><td class='name'>Cooldown</td><td class='value'>7</td></tr>"
            + "</table>"
            + "</body>"
            + "</html>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(text));
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is perfect to the question I asked. There is one more question because it has not fully solved my problem yet. Basically my program html parses String with same structures <Ability Name> Range: <Range Number> Cost: <Cost Number> Cooldown: <CD Number>. I save these individual structures into different String variables. Is it possible for me to put in a String Variable inside this html code?

Comment: That is an *entirely* different question for which you should start a [new quest1on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)!  If this Q&A is relevant to the new question, link back to it.  Don't presume that just because a person can answer one answer you ask, that they can answer *any* question you might ask.  ;)