# Integrating HTML Formatting with Java String Variables

Tags: java, html, jsoup, jlabel

[Setting Font and Colors to different parts of String that is contained in one JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583902/setting-font-and-colors-to-different-parts-of-string-that-is-contained-in-one-jl)

This link provides some previous contexts to this problem.

Basically my program html parses multiple String with same structures

[Ability Name] Range: [Range Number] Cost: [Cost Number] Cooldown: [CD Number].

I save these individual structures into different String variables. And then, I put them into a single JLabel. But I want each of these individual structures with different fonts and colors. Is it possible for me to put in a String Variable inside this html code from the link provided above?

If it is not possible, how could I make this work?

Comment: If you're asking for HTML in a JLabel, then yes you CAN do so. Java allows some HTML, so you can use `setText(String)` on your JLabel. Use regular HTML Tags for your string, however you cannot use stylesheets, as Java does not support them.

Comment: @iWumbo *"..you cannot use stylesheets, as Java does not support them."*  Sure it does.  It only implements a *limited range* of the styles defined by W3C, but it certainly supports both in-line and imported CSS.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20584326/418556) for the proof on support for in-line styles.  ..I just noticed the OP did indeed **link** to that thread!

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ah, yes....I don't know why I put we cannot use CSS. Sorry about the misinformation. Anyways, my original point is, you can use html as the OP needs it. Sorry again for that.