# CSS Style in JTable cell

Tags: java, html, swing

I am trying to put HTML into a `JTable` cell, I have tested this piece of code in IE, but the thing is, it doesn't appear as it should in a table cell. Can I confirm that it doesn't work in a table cell? Below is the HTML.

```html
<html>
<style>
div {
    *display: inline; /* For IE7 */
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
</style>
  <div>A</div><div>B</div>
  <div>A1</div><div>B1</div>
  <div>A2</div><div>B2</div>
</html>
```

I have also tried to put the style inside the `<div>`, it works in IE but not the table cell. Can anyone help?

Comment: Swing only has limited support for HTML at around 3.2 I think, it's likely that CSS isn't supported (if at all, not very highly)

Comment: *"it works in IE but.."*  Ignore what 'works in IE'.  IE was designed to take any old crap and make a good attempt at guessing what the author meant.  If you want to know that HTML 3.2 and styles are supported in an HTML enabled Swing component, check it in a `JEditorPane`.  Generally thouth, for better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: Note that CSS is malformed since it has no closing `}`..  And what the heck is the leading `*` of `*display: inline; /* For IE7 */` supposed to achieve?

Comment: @MadProgrammer  *"CSS .. if at all, not very highly"*  AFAIR it **does** cover the `display` styles.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Cool, never been able to get them to work...

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Nope.  I was wrong.. :P

Comment: @AndrewThompson There's "limited" support.  I wasn't able to get `width` or `text-align` to work, not even sure about `display` but did get `color` to work :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer  *"..wasn't able to get `width` .. to work"*  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7861833/418556) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5767825/418556) for examples that successfully use both `px` and `%` for `width`.

Answer (score 3):

It appears the attributes of the `display` style are ignored by the simple CSS engine provided with the JSE.  This source demonstrates that.  The styled text is red, but the display attribute does not change anything.

[image: HTML Display Style]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

class HTMLDisplayStyle {

    final static String EOL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    final static String HTML_PRE = "<html>" + EOL
            + "<head>" + EOL
            + "<style>" + EOL
            + "span {" + EOL
            + "color: #FF0000;" + EOL
            + "display: ";
    final static String HTML_POST = ";" + EOL
            + "}" + EOL
            + "</style>" + EOL
            + "</head>" + EOL
            + "<body>" + EOL
            + "<p>" + EOL
            + "Some text " + EOL
            + "<span>text with display style</span> " + EOL
            + "some more text." + EOL
            + "</p>" + EOL
            + "</body>" + EOL
            + "</html>" + EOL;
    final static String[] ATTRIBUTES = {
        "inline",
        "block",
        "none"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

                String s = HTML_PRE + ATTRIBUTES[0] + HTML_POST;
                final JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(s, 15, 30);
                gui.add(new JScrollPane(ta), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

                final JLabel l = new JLabel(s);
                gui.add(new JScrollPane(l));

                final JComboBox style = new JComboBox(ATTRIBUTES);
                gui.add(style, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
                ActionListener styleListener = new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        String styleAttribute = 
                                style.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        String html = HTML_PRE + styleAttribute + HTML_POST;
                        ta.setText(html);
                        l.setText(html);
                    }
                };
                style.addActionListener(styleListener);


                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```