# Whe does button not work after adding JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextpane

I created a button with JTextPane inside.
When I added JTextPane to the JButton I cant click on the button.
When I remove JTextPane I can click on the button.
Somebody know how to fix this problem?

```
public class BtnOrderFefcoStyle extends JButton {
    
        private final static String NAME_FONT = "ARIAL";
        private final static boolean IS_BOLD = true;
        private final static int SIZE_FONT = 18;
        private final static Color NAVY_COLOR = new Color(0 , 51 , 102)
        private final static int BUTTON_WIDTH  = 122;
        private final static int BUTTON_HEIGHT = 64;
        private final static int BORDER_THICKNESS = 2;
        private int posX , posY;


        public BtnOrderFefcoStyle(int pos_x , int pos_y) 
        {
            super() ;   
            this.posX = pos_x;
            this.posY= pos_y;
            setOpaque(false);
            setBorderPainted(false);
            setContentAreaFilled(false);
            setFocusable(false);
            setEnabled(true);
            setBorder(null);
            setBounds(pos_x, pos_y, BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
            setForeground(Color.WHITE);

            
            JTextPane nameBtn = new JTextPane();
            nameBtn.setEditable(false);
            nameBtn.setText("ADD TO LIST");
            nameBtn.setAutoscrolls(true);
            nameBtn.setEnabled(false);
            nameBtn.setOpaque(false);
            
            SimpleAttributeSet attribs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setAlignment(attribs, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
            StyleConstants.setFontFamily(attribs, NAME_FONT);
            StyleConstants.setBold(attribs, IS_BOLD);
            StyleConstants.setFontSize(attribs, SIZE_FONT);
            
            nameBtn.setParagraphAttributes(attribs, true);
            nameBtn.setCaretPosition(1);
            nameBtn.setParagraphAttributes(attribs, true);
            nameBtn.setDisabledTextColor(NAVY_COLOR);
            //nameBtn.setBackground(new Color(153 , 153, 153));
            nameBtn.setSize(BUTTON_WIDTH - 2 * BORDER_THICKNESS  , BUTTON_HEIGHT - 2 * BORDER_THICKNESS);
            //nameBtn.setForeground(NAVY_COLOR);
            add(nameBtn);   
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0 , 0 , BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.fillRect(BORDER_THICKNESS , BORDER_THICKNESS , BUTTON_WIDTH - 2 * BORDER_THICKNESS , BUTTON_HEIGHT  - 2 * BORDER_THICKNESS );
        }   
}
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Could you maybe show your code and explain why you are trying to add a JTextPane to a JButton? You can show text on a JButton without a JTextPane.

Comment: I would like wrap my text on the button thats why i used a JTextPane. Otherwise I can't see the text when I craeted text by JButton's constructor because i use paintComponent propably

Comment: But if thats your only wish, to make the text wrap, then why make it this complicated? This is easily done with built in functions of the JButton. Check [Word Wrap in JButtons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766175/word-wrap-in-jbuttons). You can also change the font of the displayed text with default JButton behavior.

Comment: I know that I can use ex. HTML lang. But I want to insert a raw text without any special signs. In the future Im going to import the text from a file.

Comment: With HTML you can concat the HTML tags + your raw text + closing HTML tags. You're making this too complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening in your current example is:

Your `JTextPane` is being placed on top of your `JButton` and as you removed the border from your `JButton` it's taking all the available space, so you're clicking over the `JTextPane` all the time.

If we add a border to the `JTextPane` this is what we get before removing the `JButton`'s border and after

[image] [image]

To fix this you can either:

- Add a `MouseListener` to the `JTextPane`, for example:

  ```
  nameBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
           super.mouseClicked(e);
           System.out.println("Clicked on nameBtn");
       }
  });
  ```
- create a method to use HTML as suggested in the comments above:

  ```
    private String getButtonString(String stringFromFile) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("<html><body><p>");
        sb.append(stringFromFile);
        sb.append("</p></body></html>");
        return sb.toString();
  }
  ```

This is how each of them look like when resized:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A `MouseEvent` is passed to the component that is clicked. If you add a `JTextPane` to the `JButton`, then you are clicking on the text pane, not the button.

You can tryd to remove the MouseListeners from the JTextPanel

```
for (MouseListener ml: textPane.getListeners(MouseListener.class))
    textPane.removeMouseListener( ml );
```

Not sure if you also need to remove the MouseMotionListener.