# Java swing: Multiline labels?

Tags: java, string, swing, multiline, jlabel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiline text in JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685521/multiline-text-in-jlabel)

I want to do this:

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel();
myLabel.setText("This is\na multi-line string");
```

Currently this results in a label that displays

```
This isa multi-line string
```

I want it to do this instead:

```
This is
a multi-line string
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you

---

EDIT: Implemented solution

In body of method:

```
myLabel.setText(convertToMultiline("This is\na multi-line string"));
```

Helper method:

```
public static String convertToMultiline(String orig)
{
    return "<html>" + orig.replaceAll("\n", "<br>");
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for the Label object in the SWT ?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use `HTML` in `JLabels`. To use it, your text has to start with `<html>`.

Set your text to `"<html>This is<br>a multi-line string"` and it should work.

See [Swing Tutorial: JLabel](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JLabel.html) and [Multiline label (HTML)](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/MultilinelabelHTML.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 22):

```
public class JMultilineLabel extends JTextArea{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public JMultilineLabel(String text){
        super(text); // According to Mr. Polywhirl, this might improve it -> text + System.lineSeparator()
        setEditable(false);  
        setCursor(null);  
        setOpaque(false);  
        setFocusable(false);  
        setFont(UIManager.getFont("Label.font"));      
        setWrapStyleWord(true);  
        setLineWrap(true);
        //According to Mariana this might improve it
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));  
        setAlignmentY(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    }
}
```

It totally looks the same for me, but its ugly

Comment: It's not ugly at all!  I ended up building on this by having my component extend JScrollPane which in turn wrapped a JTextArea configured exactly as you have here.  Wrapping in the JScrollPane allows the thing to shrink back down after it has be resized to a larger width.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer! To beautify it a bit, you could also remove the line border, add insets, and align center verically:  setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)); 
 setAlignmentY(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

Comment: I had to call `super(text + System.lineSeparator());` to prevent the bottom of the label from getting cut-off.

Answer (score 7):

Another easy way (but changes the text style a bit) is to use a `<pre></pre>` html block.

This will persist any formatting the user entered if the string you are using came from a user input box.

Example:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><pre>First Line\nSecond Line</pre></html>");
```

Comment: Nice catch. But it must be mentioned that this also changes font (to monospaced), which is not always desired.

Answer (score 5):

JLabel can accept html code. Maybe you can try to use the `<br>` tag.

Example:

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel();
myLabel.setText("<html> This is a <br> multi-line string </html>");
```

Answer (score 5):

The direct procedure of writing a multi-line text in a jlabel is:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>First Line<br>Second Line</html>");
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem with using html in `JLabel` or any Swing component is that you then have to style it as html, not with the usual `setFont`, `setForeground`, etc. If you're ok with that, fine.

Otherwise you can use something like [MultilineLabel](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/swing/MultilineLabel.html) from JIDE, which extends `JTextArea`. It's part of their open source [Commom Layer](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm).

Answer (score 1):

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html