# Can Java AWT List's be multi line?

Tags: java, listbox, awt

Can I easily make a `java.awt.List` multi line for each cell?

E.G. if the cell contains "Hello" It will be height of say 5, and if it contains a considerably longer string "Hello there good day sir" it would adjust the height to 10 and place the remainder on the next line but still be the same selection?

Comment: Not sure about `java.awt.List` (that's pretty ancient anyway), but with `javax.swing.JList` (that's a little newer) one can use a custom cell renderer capable of multi-line display. The renderer can be e.g. based on a `JTextArea`, as is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152742/java-swing-multiline-labels

Comment: 1) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing. 2) *"Can I easily make a java.awt.List multi line for each cell?"* No.