# JLabel help in java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

I am using a GUI to display information about "members" in my program database. I want to display a user bio, but it is getting cut off. How do I make my JLabel longer, or allow for it to use multiple lines?

Thanks!

Comment: Show your tried code please.

Comment: Please show code and tell details. Let us understand your problem more fully if possible.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid a fuller description of your problem and what you have tried to solve it is necessary.  I *think* I know what you want and even how to solve it, as I'm sure Hovercraft does, but it isn't even worth it to type it up unless we know more about what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

The length depends on the layout manager and how you use it. You can also use setPreferredSize(Dimension preferredSize). For the multiple lines part, I think your question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685521/multiline-text-in-jlabel)

Answer (score 0):

JLabel extends [JComponent](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/jdk/jdk-api-localizations/jdk-api-zh-cn/builds/latest/html/en/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html); I believe you want to use [setPreferredSize(Dimension size)](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/jdk/jdk-api-localizations/jdk-api-zh-cn/builds/latest/html/en/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29).