# Break a String to use html in jlabel

Tags: java, html, string, split, jlabel

Here is my code :

```
JLabel JL_Output = new JLabel(Reponse);
JL_Output.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Output: "));
JL_Output.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 175));
JL_Output.setBackground(Color.red);
```

So my probleme is that my Response String its too long to be viewed in one line.
So I want to use the html with the /br nut I can't integrat these balise because I can't "enter" in the String :/

I would like to display in 4 lines, like this
Response value :

```
Enter the angle offset
   Units   : [degrees]
   Range   : [-090<+090]
   Current : [+000]                 >>  ERROR
```

Comment: Does using `\n` in the string to represent a new line work?

Comment: Unfornutly I can't change the response I'm getting :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Response` is a string, you could do something like so:

```
String formattedResponse = Response.replaceAll("\\]", "\\]<br />");
JLabel JL_Output = new JLabel(formattedResponse);
...
```

That should replace all closing brackets with a closed bracket and a breakline statement, which should do what you need.

EDIT: As per your comment, you could use something like the code below to do what you need:

```
String formattedResponse = Response.replaceAll("\\s{4,}", "<br />");
JLabel JL_Output = new JLabel("<html>" + formattedResponse + "</html>");
```

The code above will match any piece of the `Response` string that is made up from 4 or more consecutive white space characters and replace them with a `<br />`.

Comment: Yes sure this would work only for this response but I have like 100 of response possible. Is it just possible to put a </br> if there is more than 4 blank space ?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the logical, I will let you know if it worked. Thanks

Comment: @D3fman: Ok. Just an FYI, I had a small typo in my edit (missed a set of quotation marks) so make sure you do not make my same mistake.

Comment: Last small question, how can you put <html> in the begining of the string ?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I forgot the "" -_-

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your description, that the text you receive is to long for one line and has no line breaks in it? So why don't you create a second String with line breaks in the places you want?

**But maybe you could just use "JTextarea" an disable it, to make it not modifiable:**

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(
  "This is an editable JTextArea. " +
  "A text area is a \"plain\" text component, " +
  "which means that although it can display text " +
  "in any font, all of the text is in the same font."
);
textArea.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 16));
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

Of course you can transform your string into HTML. 
See this article to find out how line breaks work:
[Multiline text in JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685521/multiline-text-in-jlabel)

Comment: The thing is how do you get in the reponse text ? because the reponse is something that is generate by a device and I get the response by doing a readSerialPort then I convert the reponse in bytes into String type.

Comment: Yes but you can copy and modify the text. Like taking 40 characters, insert a line break, and take the next 40 characters and insert the next line break ... and so on.

After that you have a new string including line breaks which can be displayed.

Comment: Try with JTextArea is much simpler :-)