# Multiline text label in WindowBuilder?

Tags: java, windowbuilder

Is it possible to create multiline label in WindowBuilder?

Methods below failed:

1) JLabel with `\n`-s

2) JLabel with text, wrapper into `<html>` and `maximuSize` set

3) JTextPane with and withot `<html>`

Why???

Comment: I don't use WindowBuilder, but when I need multiline labels in Java, I use <html> with <br>.

Comment: You asked about a label, so I assumed you meant a JLabel. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685521/multiline-text-in-jlabel

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display multiline text in a JLabel, use html tags like this:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>First line and maybe second line</html>");
```

If you want to be able to control the line-break, use standard html 
 tags:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>First line<br>Second line</html>");
```