# JLabel set as text list items

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I have a list that contains `String`s and I am trying to set its items as `JLabel` text, the only problem is that the result is a single line

```
JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
btnSearch.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        String fileName = textField.getText();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        List <String> searchResult = new Search().cautaFisiere("C:\\AdwCleaner", fileName);

        for (int x = 0; x < searchResult.size(); x++) {
            result.append(searchResult.get(x)).append("\n");

        }
        lblNewLabel.setText(result.toString());
    }

});
```

As you can see I tried appending items as new line but no result. I also tried `append(System.getProperty("line.separator"))` but still no result, the text is still displayed in one line

Comment: Are you trying to print all the items in list on the label?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: Can you print `result` and see if it is empty?

Comment: Uma Kanth it is not empty, and I can print the results on the label as a single line, but I want them printed as a list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiline text in JLabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685521/multiline-text-in-jlabel)

Comment: I tried doing it. The result was the same, it just prints in a single line.

Comment: why not use JTable for this?

Comment: If you want to display the contents of a file then `JLabel` is the wrong component. Consider using a multi-line text component like `JTextArea` (and use `jtextarea.setEditable(false)` to make it read-only).

Comment: Quota I am trying to display the contents of a list, JTextArea is for text editing

Comment: That's what `setEditable(false)` is for. Then you have a perfectly fine component to display text. Works nearly out of the box (don't forget scroll panes--which you'd need for the label, too...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in here [Multiline text in JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685521/multiline-text-in-jlabel), just can just use HTML tag `<br>` to make a new line, but it must be in `<html></html>` tags.

```
JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
btnSearch.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        String fileName = textField.getText();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        List <String> searchResult = new Search().cautaFisiere("C:\\AdwCleaner", fileName);

        for (int x = 0; x < searchResult.size(); x++) {
            result.append(searchResult.get(x)).append("<br>");
        }
        lblNewLabel.setText("<html>" + result.toString() + "</html>");
    }
});
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for