# How to show arraylist as a seperate jlabels in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I have an arraylist of city names and I want to show them as a bottom up jlabels. How can I do that?

```
   ArrayList<String> cityNames = new ArrayList<>(columnCount); 

                while(resultSet.next()){
                    int i = 1;
                       while(i <= columnCount) {
                           cityNames.add(resultSet.getString(i++));
                       }            
                }

                //Loop through cityNames as seperate Jlabels
            for(String city : cityNames){
                cityLabel.setText(city);
            }
```

Comment: What happens if you make a `JLabel` for each string?  That seems like the straightforward solution

Comment: Then It outputs the end value.

Comment: What "end" value?

Comment: I have edited the code. If you mean this. It outputs only the last value.

Comment: Your edit makes it look like you only want one label.  Do you want jlabel**s** or jlabel?

Comment: Multiple jlabels so that is what I could not do.

Comment: What if you try my initial comment, of making a `JLabel` for each string? (`for(String city : cityNames) panel.add(new JLabel(city));`)

Comment: Okay that is the solution I think thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create multiple `JLabel`s and add them to a panel

```
JPanel panel = [...];
ArrayList<String> cityNames = [...];

for(String city : cityNames)
    panel.add(new JLabel(city));
```

---

If you need to do something with them later, add them to a `List` as well

```
JPanel panel = [...];
ArrayList<String> cityNames = [...];
List<JLabel> cityLabels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();

for(String city : cityNames)
{
    JLabel label = new JLabel(city);
    cityLabels.add(label);
    panel.add(label);
}
```

---

If you just want all of the city names in one `JLabel` [(can be on multiple lines)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/685631/5475891)

```
ArrayList<String> cityNames = [...];

String cities = "";
for(String city : cityNames)
    cities += ", " + city; //or use "<br>" for separate lines
cities = cities.substring(2); //remove the first ", "

JLabel cityLabel = new JLabel(cities); //add this to your rendering panel
```